# Error "unsupported architecture: xxx requires SSE4.1 & SSE4.2

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm trying to install a package and at the install phase I came across the following error :
"unsupported architecture; xxx requires SSE4.1 & SSE4.2"
[image: pic1]

However as I checked my cpu (2GHz Quad-Core intel i5) does support SSE4.1 & SSE4.2 as shown in the following attachment[image: pic2]

I found no similar solution to this elsewhere. Appreciate if anyone could help.

PS. I'm running Ubuntu on Virtualbox, could be some setting of VirtualBox that hinders the process?

Comment: One would have to look at what `config.hpp` is actually testing.  What's the program you're trying to compile?

Comment: What version of VirtualBox?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not too familar with C++, but the corresponding section is 

#if defined(__AVX2__)
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX2() 1
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX() 1
#elif defined(__AVX__)
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX2() 0
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX() 1
#elif defined(__SSE4_2__) && defined(__SSE4_1__)
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX2() 0
#    define TCM_HAS_AVX() 0
#else
#    error "unsupported architecture; nqs-playground requires SSE4.1 & SSE4.2"
#endif

I'm trying to manually install a package.

Comment: @fpmurphy I'm using virtualbox 6.1.18 for your info